# Консольное окно

Tags: java, консоль

Здравствуйте.

Не успеваю просмотреть содержимое. Консольное окно сразу закрывается. Как его оставить открытым?
Какой командой java можно остановить консольное окно?

Comment: @Александр1111, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

Попробуй запускать из "командной строки" (Пуск > выполнить > cmd.exe)... Если лень каждый раз набирать, напиши простой bat файл. В нем после строчек с запуском компилятора и выполнения "main класса" напиши pause.

Пример bat-файла myrun.bat:

```
@echo on

javac HelloWorld.java

java -classpath . HelloWorld

pause
```

Про работу с Java в командной строке можешь почитать тут: http://habrahabr.ru/post/125210/

Answer (score 2):

Давно не писал на Java, что-то вроде

```
 int c = System.in.read();
```

будет ждать ввода с клавиатуры.

--

[@Александр1111](/users/26897/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%801111), а Вы в какой IDE обучаетесь? Помнится в eclipse таких проблем не было.

Comment: В Eclipse, при отладке программы консольное окно программы Eclipse показывает содержимое, но при сохранении в jar-файл и запуске программы консольное окно windows сразу же закрывается. Не успеваю посмотреть содержимое.

Comment: Значит, либо мне память изменяет, либо в Eclipse этот момент поменяли, либо я чего-то в вопросе не понял.

Тогда или запускайте просто из командной строки, или вставляйте  чтение перед выходом (понимаю, что не всегда это возможно).

Answer (score 0):

Окно закроется после завершения приложения. Для завершения приложения в любом месте можно использовать System.exit()

Comment: Спасибо, только проблема в обратном как его остановить, потому что не успеваю просматривать содержимое.

Comment: system("pause"), getch()
Да чего в него глядеть-то. Ничего хорошего там нет. :-)

Comment: Благодарю Вас

Comment: Можно поподробнее, как применять `system("pause"), getch()`, все подчеркнуто красным цветом, из какого они пространства имен?

Comment: BuilderC, в Java нет систем паузы и гетча.

Comment: А где сказано, что это Java?

Comment: 2BuilderC, "Какой командой java можно остановить консольное окно",  вторая строка вопроса